# Python While Loop Square

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a beginner at Python and I'm trying to use a `while loop` to sum up all of the squared `n` values in a given `n` value range.

Code:

```
def problem2(n):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while x < n:
        y = (n**2)+y
        x+=1
    return y
```

For some reason, this equation returns the input number cubed.

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform the `**` on `x`, the value that is being incremented:

```
def problem2(n):
  x = 0
  count = 0
  while x < n:
    count += pow(x, 2)
    x += 1
  return count
```

Answer (score 2):

You keep squaring the same number `n`, instead of the one being incremented `x`.

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(0, n):
        sum += x*x
    return sum
```

Answer (score 2):

You also don't really need the `while` loop, avoiding having to manually keep track of which variable is the counting variable and which one is the result variable (which is what you are confusing, as explained e.g. by [@Ajax1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7326738/ajax1234) in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352315/4042267)).

It is a lot more Pythonic to use the built-in function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and `range`:

```
def problem2(n):
    return sum(x**2 for x in range(n))
```

This would be a lot more readable and better (unless of course you are being *forced* to use `while`).

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @IliaCholy It fixes the problem by not using a `while` loop (fixing the problem being one part of the question). As to the why, the answer by Ajax and your own already sufficiently explain that so I did not want to repeat it.

Comment: I think this is great for both solving the original problem *and* coming up with your own solution

Answer (score 2):

Looks good. You're almost there.

It makes it the cube root because you add y to `(n**2)` everytime. Because you code runs until `x !< n` it runs n times. That means that you add `n**2` to `n**2*n`.

That means that it gives `1(n**2)*(n-1)(n**2)` which equals `n(n**2) = n**3`

Hope this was clear enough.